# Remove specific html code using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algorithm

```
<div id="mn">

    <p article="game" a_type="advertisement" cid="#P6_001"></p> 
    <p article="let" cid="#P6_005"></p> 
    <dc_title article="start" check_zone="true" a_type="masthead" cid="#P6_006"></dc_title> 
    <p article="end" cid="#P6_047"></p> 
    <p article="start" a_type="advertisement" cid="#P6_001"></p> 
    <p article="end" cid="#P6_005"></p> 
    <dc_title article="sd" check_zone="true" a_type="masthead" cid="#P6_006"></dc_title> 
    <p article="end" cid="#P6_047"></p> 
</div>
```

i have a code like that. i wanna remove tags that have article="start" attribute and next tag has article="end"

```
<dc_title article="start" check_zone="true" a_type="masthead" cid="#P6_006"></dc_title> 
<p article="end" cid="#P6_047"></p>
```

so after fix above code i wanna display it like this:

```
<p article="game" a_type="advertisement" cid="#P6_001"></p> 
<p article="let" cid="#P6_005"></p> 
<dc_title article="sd" check_zone="true" a_type="masthead" cid="#P6_006"></dc_title> 
<p article="end" cid="#P6_047"></p>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/remove/ - mind you I don't see ids or classes on your html so that may pose a problem.

Comment: @krupalshah i tried jquery $.each

Comment: @Supun then write in question..not in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to use jQuery (or if it's possible in your project), you can do the following:

```
elements = $('[article="start"] + [article="end"]');
elements.prev().detach();
elements.detach();
```

The first line selects all elements that have `article=end` directly preceded by an element with `article=start`. The second line deletes the `article=start` elements and the third line deletes the `article=end` elements.

Comment: answer this too plz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348950/remove-add-specific-html-using-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using jquery [jsfiddle work out](http://jsfiddle.net/8qtv8vch/2/).

```
     var selector1=$( 'p[article="start"]');
     var selector2=$( 'dc_title[article="start"]');
     selector2.next('p[article="end"]').remove();
     selector1.next('p[article="end"]').remove();
     selector1.remove();
     selector2.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get reference to the nodes with `var dv = getElementsByAttribute('article','start');`

```
for(var i=0;i<dv.length;i++){
 if(dv[i].nextSibling.getAttribute('article')=="end")
    var ref = dv[i];
    ref.parentNode.removeChild(ref.nextSibling);
    dv[i].parentNode.removeChild(dv[i]); 

 }



var getElementsByAttribute = function (attr, value) {
  var match = [];

  /* Get the droids we're looking for*/
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

  /* Loop through all elements */
  for (var ii = 0, ln = elements.length; ii < ln; ii++) {

    if (elements[ii].hasAttribute(attr)) {

      /* If a value was passed, make sure it matches the element's */
      if (value) {

        if (elements[ii].getAttribute(attr) === value) {
          match.push(elements[ii]);
        }
      } else {
        /* Else, simply push it */
        match.push(elements[ii]);
      }
    }
  }
  return match;
};
```