# add/remove specific html using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code like this:

```
<div id="sd">

    <dc_title article="start" check_zone="true" a_type="cover" cid="#P1_001"></dc_title>
    <p article_con="1.1" cid="#P1_013"></p>
    <p article="start" a_type="advertisement" cid="#P2_001"></p>
    <p article_con="2.1" cid="#P2_004"></p>
    <p article_con="2.1" cid="#P3_001"></p>
    <p article_con="2.1" cid="#P3_005"></p>
    <p article_con="2.1" cid="#P4_001"></p>
    <p article="end" cid="#P4_002"></p>
    <dc_title article="start" check_zone="true" a_type="tableOfContents" cid="#P5_001"></dc_title>
    <dc_title article="start" check_zone="true" create_section="true" a_type="article" cid="#P14_001"></dc_title>
    <p article_con="14.1" cid="#P14_040"></p>
    <p article_con="14.1" cid="#P16_005"></p>
    <p article="end" cid="#P16_018"></p>

</div>
```

and there are 3 special attributes:

```
article="start"
article_con="...."
article="end"
```

- I want to check that first line tag has an `article="start"` attribute and last line tag has an `article="end"` attribute.
- I want to find are there any two same tags near like that (minding only attribute):

  ```
  <p article="end" cid="#P4_002"></p>
  <p article="end" cid="#P4_002"></p>
  ```

  OR

  ```
  <p article="start" cid="#P4_001"></p>
  <p article="start" cid="#P4_002"></p>
  ```

  OR `article_con="..."` has same value and odd number of tag:

  ```
  <p article_con="2.1" cid="#P3_001"></p>
  <p article_con="2.1" cid="#P3_002"></p>
  <p article_con="2.1" cid="#P3_003"></p>
  ```

Comment: The title is not related to the question at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sdChilds = $( "#sd" ).children();
if (($sdChilds.first().attr('article') == 'start') && ($sdChilds.last().attr('article') == 'end')){
    alert('Yes, first and last tags are Start and End');
}else{
    alert('No, first and last tags are not Start and End');
}

var prevArticle = '*';
var prevArticleCon = '*';
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
$("p, dc_title" ).each(function(){
    if (($(this).attr('article') == prevArticle) && (prevArticle != null)){
        i++;
    }
    if (($(this).attr('article_con') == prevArticleCon) && (prevArticleCon != null)){
        j++;
    }
    prevArticle = $(this).attr('article');
    prevArticleCon = $(this).attr('article_con');
});
if (i > 0){
    alert('Yes, you have '+ i + ' extra element with same article attribute');
}
if (j > 0){
    alert('Yes, you have '+ j + ' extra element with same article_con attribute');
}
```

**[Check this JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r4rx1k4L/2/)**

You can change the `HTML` code and check if it's works as you want or not.
Try to add or remove start and end tags and add or remove tags with repeated attributes and check the code.

Comment: The answer, when I left the original comment, was a link to code posted elsewhere, with only minor commentary posted in your 'answer.' My downvote was simply to address that lack, and retracted once you posted your code here (as you should have done originally). I won't comment on how easy the code might be, because to me the *question* is illegible, so I can't assess the correctness of your answer.